# how to add hash mapping content to text file

Tags: java, collections

Hi I am having Hashmap content as

```
mapping :{[unknown, unknown, nicholas@123.com, nicholas@123.com, nicholas@123.com, WHEEL@123.com, WHEEL@123.com]=[STANDARD CHARTERED B, STANDARD CHARTERED B, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK (HONG KONG), DBS BANK (HONG KONG)], [unknown, unknown, nicholas@123.com, nicholas@123.com, nicholas@123.com, WHEEL@123.com, WHEEL@123.com]=[STANDARD CHARTERED B, STANDARD CHARTERED B, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK (HONG KONG), DBS BANK (HONG KONG)], [unknown, unknown, nicholas@123.com, nicholas@123.com, nicholas@123.com, WHEEL@123.com, WHEEL@123.com]=[STANDARD CHARTERED B, STANDARD CHARTERED B, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK (HONG KONG), DBS BANK (HONG KONG)], [unknown, unknown, nicholas@123.com, nicholas@123.com, nicholas@123.com, WHEEL@123.com, WHEEL@123.com]=[STANDARD CHARTERED B, STANDARD CHARTERED B, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK (HONG KONG), DBS BANK (HONG KONG)], [unknown, unknown, nicholas@123.com, nicholas@123.com, nicholas@123.com, WHEEL@123.com, WHEEL@123.com]=[STANDARD CHARTERED B, STANDARD CHARTERED B, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK (HONG KONG), DBS BANK (HONG KONG)], [unknown, unknown, nicholas@123.com, nicholas@123.com, nicholas@123.com, WHEEL@123.com, WHEEL@123.com]=[STANDARD CHARTERED B, STANDARD CHARTERED B, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK (HONG KONG), DBS BANK (HONG KONG)], [unknown, unknown, nicholas@123.com, nicholas@123.com, nicholas@123.com, WHEEL@123.com, WHEEL@123.com]=[STANDARD CHARTERED B, STANDARD CHARTERED B, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK LIMITED HON, DBS BANK (HONG KONG), DBS BANK (HONG KONG)]}
```

I want to add it to file as only unique values with its mapping

```
unknown STANDARD CHARTERED B
nicholas@123.com DBS BANK LIMITED HON
WHEEL@123.com DBS BANK (HONG KONG)
```

My java code is as below ....

```
System.out.println("mapping :"+compIdmap);


            Iterator<Entry<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>>> it = compIdmap.entrySet().iterator();

            while (it.hasNext()){
                Entry<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>> line = it.next();
                String entryLine = line.getKey() + " -> " + line.getValue();
                br1.write(entryLine);
                }
```

Its not writing in mapping format ... 1 line of hashmap is adding .. I want only unique elements of hashmap to be added to text file.

Comment: sorry what's the expected output? why not use jackson/Gson etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

create another `HashMap` to add unique values

```
  HashMap<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

add items in new hashmap

```
hashmap.put(keys[i], values[i]);
```

``

```
   Iterator<Entry<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>>> it =  compIdmap.entrySet().iterator();
   HashMap<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
        Entry<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>> line = it.next();
        String keys[] = line.getKey().split(",");
        String values[] = line.getValue().split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            hashmap.put(keys[i], values[i]);
        }
    }
```

Iterate Map and Write File

```
   Iterator iterator = mp.entrySet().iterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
        String entryLine=pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue();
        br1.write(entryLine);
        //write  here in file ...........
    }
}
```